# Possible Betti numbers of smooth complex varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology

Given a smooth projective complex variety $X$ of dimension $n$, there are various restrictions on its sequence of Betti numbers $b_0, b_1, ..., b_{2n}$. Of course, $b_0=b_{2n}=1$ and $b_i=b_{2n-i}$ by Poincaré duality. By the hard Lefschetz theorem, we also know that $b_k \le b_{k+2}$ for $k <n$. Furthermore $b_1, b_3, ..., b_{2n-1}$ have to be even (This follows from Hodge decomposition). Are there further neccessary conditions for the numbers $b_0, b_1, ..., b_{2n}$ to be the Betti numbers of a projective variety?

(I'd also be happy to learn about sufficient criteria, but I guess that there are probably no substantial results in that direction.)

Comment: Actually I wouldn't be surprised if there were reasonable sufficient conditions -- you just have to construct examples. This was done, in the case $X$ toric (the Upper Bound Theorem).

Comment: Stefan Schreieder, "On the Construction Problem for Hodge Numbers" (arXiv:1301.0478) does some things in the direction of both necessary and sufficient conditions.  See Corollary 4 for a result on the Betti numbers.